# Android - how to make Array<String> into a string for recognizer results

Tags: java, android

I need the results from recognizer to be a string.. when i use this code i get eclipse error 'cannot convert Array as string..

```
code: final ArrayList<String> results2 = data.getStringArrayListExtra    (RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
```

also tried, with no luck:

```
final String results2 = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
```

still says error..

Is this enough info?? Thank you in advance.

NEW: I added this code, but i want a .get that will store this word/text in acceptable manner for a cursor usage:

```
String[] matches = data.getStringArrayExtra(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
```

Eclipse does not error , but my result is coming out as 'null' so i just need a .Get that works in my scenario??  Than kyou all for helping also!

Comment: What, exactly, are you trying to do? An `ArrayList` is most certainly not a `String`

Comment: i need the word spoken from recognizer into this: ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver(); Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + "=?", new String[]{ results2 }, null); where u see 'results2' is where i need that line from code above to be the string, i think.. sorry noob.. ?

Comment: What is the method signature for data.getStringArrayListExtra? specifically, what exactly does it return?

Comment: ok, it returns the word user spoke into recognizer SPEACHtoTEXT. so if I said out loud to device 'please help' it would return the text 'please help'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you code should work fine. See this snippet:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    final ArrayList<String> stringArrayListExtra = i.getStringArrayListExtra("hello");
}
```

What you can look is:

- check for your java version. Do you have java 1.5 (or higher but I am not very confortable with 1.7 yet) configured. The reason this that generics are added in 1.5.
- Try cleaning and rebuilding your project by choosing Project > Clean.

I can't see any other

Edit: Since there is not enough code to look into, you can yourself look into [speech sample here](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/VoiceRecognition.html)

If look there:

```
/**
 * Handle the results from the recognition activity.
 */
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        // Fill the list view with the strings the recognizer thought it could have heard
        ArrayList<String> matches = data.getStringArrayListExtra(
                RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
        mList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                matches));
    }

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

They are using `RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS`. Try this sample if it resolves your issue. As now your issue is different then what i look initially.

Comment: Please look above, added additional info to help.. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
@Override
    public void onResults(Bundle results) {
ArrayList<String> matches = results.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
[...]
```

**/edit:**
Sorry, like I said, I mixed that up. Have you checked the request code? Normally this should work:

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        ArrayList<String> matches = data.getStringArrayListExtra(
                RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

However, this is actually almost exactly the code you are using - try it nethertheless, as it has `super.onActivityResult()` in the end.

Comment: before suggestion, i had super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); at bottom of my onActivityResult.. do i remove it, maybe wont work, or u have update for that?

Comment: Oh I see, I mixed it up - I thought your are using a `SpeechRecognizer`, not that SpeechRecognition Activity. See my updated answer.